# Separate model definitions and model code

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I wish to re-use the .json - Files of the models and share them between different services. The services have very different concerns but want to operate on the same data structures. In order to avoid duplication of effort and errors, I would like to put the .json - Files into a package and associate the Javascript - Files with the model files separately in each project. Example:

A directory only for the .json definitions that can be shared among various applications accessing the same data source:

```
models 
- ModelA.json
- ModelB.json
- ...
```

Per application a directory with the application specific logic:

```
model-logic
- ModelA.js
- ModelB.js
- ...
```

If I try this with loopback, the model files can be found, but unless the Javascript files are in the same directory, they are not associated with the models. Is there a way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of LoopBack and the author of loopback-boot module.*

In LoopBack, we have a set of APIs for registering new models, and then a conventional bootstrapper (the loopback-boot module) that defines a convention for project layout and calls LoopBack APIs to automatically load and define model from JSON and JS files. As you have correctly observed, loopback-boot assumes both JS and JSON files are in the same location.

To support the case where each application wants to define custom model methods, few solutions come to my mind.

### Option 1: Model inheritance

You can leverage model inheritance:

- The models defined in the shared module (package) provide only properties (data schema).
- For each shared model, an application can define a subclassed model inheriting from the shared model. The JSON file can be very simple (just model `name` and `base` model name to inherit from, plus perhaps remoting metadata for your custom methods).

Package containing shared models:

```
- BaseModelA.json
- (empty BaseModelA.js that can be omitted)
- BaseModelB.json
- (empty BaseModelB.js that can be omitted)
- ...
```

In your app, let's create ModelA inheriting from ModelB and adding additional behavior:

- common/models/ModelA.json

  ```
  {
    "name": "ModelA",
    "base": "BaseModelA",
  }
  ```
- common/models/ModelA.js

  ```
  'use strict';

  module.exports = function(ModelA) {
    // place your code here
  }
  ```

The missing piece is to tell loopback-boot to look for models in your shared package. Assuming your package is called "models", contains the models in `common/models` directory and gets installed to `node_modules/models`, you need to edit your `server/model-config.json` as follows:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "models/common/models", // <-- ADD THIS LINE
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    // etc.
  },
  // etc.
}
```

### Option 2: load models your way

Alternatively, you don't have to use loopback-boot to setup your application runtime, you can write your own conventional bootstrapper.

Here are the APIs to use:

- Data sources are defined via `app.dataSource(name, config)` ([apidocs](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#app-datasource)). To define datasources, loopback-boot essentially loads `datasources.json` and iterates through all top-level properties, calling `app.dataSource(key, data[key])`.
- Models are loaded in multiple steps:

  1. If you are using mixins, then you need load them first. The API is not surfaced at `app` level, you have to call `app.registry.modelBuilder.mixins.define(fn)` ([source](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/1ef38a6929ae100c73030b720097ba5c4b90a7b3/lib/mixins.js#L60-L74)).
  2. A model needs to be defined first by calling `app.registry.createModel(config)`, where `config` argument is set to the content of a model JSON file.
  3. Once you have the model constructor, you need to attach it to a datasource and expose it via the REST API by calling `app.model(ModelCtor, config)`. The `config` argument contains model configuration from `server/model-config.json` file, for example `{dataSource: 'db', public: true}`.

To load the remaining artifacts (app config, middleware config, components, etc.), it may be best to keep using loopback-boot. Just tell the bootstrapper there are no models nor datasources to load.

```
const app = loopback();

// 1. load your datasources and models
// (TODO)

// 2. use loopback-boot to do the rest
boot(
  app, 
  {
    appRootDir: __dirname, 
    models: {}, 
    dataSources: {},
    modelSources: [],
    mixinSources: [],
  });

// etc.
```

*(The example above is for `loopback-boot@2.x`, I am not familiar with the configuration options of the new version `loopback-boot@3.x`.)*

Comment: Inheritance does not reduce the effort much in our case and somewhat bloats the code. I tried it and found it unappetising. 

I read the source code for the loopback 3.x way (which is what we are using). In the compiler.js method, you can see the model .js files are expected to be colocated to the model.json files. 

I am very sceptical about 'patching' a framework in this manner. In my experience this is very brittle towards upgrades. However in this case it might be our only option to weigh against copy & paste.

Comment: I would love an advanced option in the model-config.json file, that would allow one to link the .json file with the .js file. I think the effort to make it so would be manageable. Something like 'modelCodeDirectory'. Do you think that would be possible to add to the list of features?

Comment: @IonTichy I am afraid StackOverflow is rather impractical for this discussion, could you please open an issue in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot and mention my GitHub handle (bajtos) so that I get a notification?